# loop over file and make dir with 1st columns and and wget using the other columns

Tags: linux, awk, scripting, wget, mkdir

I have a file like this with multiple rows-

```
GSE55555 ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE55nnn/GSE55555/suppl/* ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE55nnn/GSE55555/matrix/*
GSE11111 ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE11nnn/GSE11111/suppl/* ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE11nnn/GSE11111/matrix/*
```

I want to make dir using 1st column and store the downloaded files from 2nd and 3rd column in that directory.

How can I go about it in unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex **`bash`** + **`wget`** solution:

```
while read -r d f1 f2; do 
    mkdir -p "$d" && cd "$d"
    wget --no-verbose -nd -np -r --level=1 "$f1"
    wget --no-verbose -nd -np -r --level=1 "$f2"
    cd $OLDPWD
done <inputfile
```

---

*Details*:

- `read -r d f1 f2` - read 3 fields from each line from the `inputfile` into respective variables `d`(directory name), `f1`(filepath 1) and `f2`(filepath 2)
- `mkdir -p "$d" && cd "$d` - creating new directory if not exists and change the current working directory to that folder
- `wget --no-verbose -nd -np -r --level=1 "$f1"` - download all files on the 1st level of hierarchy (`--level=1`) from filepath `$f1`
- `cd $OLDPWD` - back to previous working directory

---

Viewing results:

```
$ tree GSE*
GSE11111
├── filelist.txt
├── GSE11111_RAW.tar
└── GSE11111_series_matrix.txt.gz
GSE55555
├── filelist.txt
├── GSE55555_RAW.tar
├── GSE55555_repset.17402833.enrichment.clusters.gff3.gz
└── GSE55555_series_matrix.txt.gz

0 directories, 7 files
```